# Custom style user profile pages in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, variables, drupal-6, user-profile

I wish to display my tabs (View / Edit etc.) in a sidebar and not on top of the node but only when I am viewing my own profile (maybe when viewing other users profiles too). In my page.tpl.php I have this snippet:

```
<?php if (!empty($tabs)): ?><div class="tabs-wrapper"><?php print $tabs; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

And I guess it should be something like `if (!empty($tabs) && !$user_profile_page)` but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do this using multiple template files in your theme. In your theme you need to copy page.tpl.php and rename it to either:

```
 page-user.tpl.php
```

(theme all user profile pages at once)

```
 page-user-<id>.tpl.php
```

(theme a particular user's profile (where `<id>` is the user id)

Then you just style those particular template files with the tabs you want (no if statements required).